# Integer in a string python

Tags: python, input

so I am trying to get a small little addition game working. I have a random number generator working.

```
    import random


    num1 = gen(10)
    num2 = gen(10)
    answer = int(input('What is', num1, '+', num2))
    print(answer)
```

I just want the input line to ask the program to ask "what is (random number)+(random number)"

Comment: What is the problem? [Random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555712/generate-a-random-number/5555738#5555738)? Errors with input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this python 3 or python 2?

Regardless of which version of python you are using, input requires a single argument - In this case a string.

You thus need to create a string which contains the numbers. There are several ways to do this:

```
"What is %s + %s"%(num1, num2)
```

or

```
"What is "+str(num1)+" + "+str(num2)
```

or

```
"What is {} + {}".format(num1, num2)
```

Earlier versions of python may not work with the last example, but at least one should be okay.

I would also advise that you enclose your conversion of an input to an int in a try, to prevent users creating exceptions by entering something that isn't an int.

```
while 1:
    try:
        answer = int(input("What is {} + {}".format(num1, num2))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Try again.."
```

For example with something like that

Answer (score 2):

```
answer = int(input('What is ' + str(num1) + '+' + str(num2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
answer = int(input('What is %d + %d? ' % (num1, num2)))
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: I suggest you to search for 'python format string'. Basically, this is like `printf` in other languages.

Comment: Add that to your answer, I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
answer = raw_input(print("what is %d + %d" (num1, num2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

num1 = gen(10)
num2 = gen(10)

sum = num1    #The sum of your 2 random numbers

correct = False

while not correct:  
    #If they haven't answered correctly, keep asking the question, otherwise move on.
    answer = int(input('What is', num1, '+', num2))

    if answer == sum:
        print("Correct! The answer was: ", answer)
        correct = True
    else:
        print("Incorrect, try again!")
```